# warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds] when compiling using -O3 flag

Tags: c, arrays, bounds

I still cannot understand why I got this warning `array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]` for a small C code as the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int _memcmp( const void *x, const void *y, size_t size ){
    const char *s1 = (char*)x, *s2 = (char*)y;

    int ret;
    ret = s1[0] - s2[0];
    if ( size == 1 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[1] - s2[1];
    if ( size == 2 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[2] - s2[2];
    if ( size == 3 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[3] - s2[3];
    if ( size == 4 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[4] - s2[4];
    if ( size == 5 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[5] - s2[5];
    if ( size == 6 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[6] - s2[6];
    if ( size == 7 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[7] - s2[7];
    if ( size == 8 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[8] - s2[8];
    if ( size == 9 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[9] - s2[9];
    if ( size == 10 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

//0-20
    ret = s1[10] - s2[10];
    if ( size == 11 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[11] - s2[11];
    if ( size == 12 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[12] - s2[12];
    if ( size == 13 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[13] - s2[13];
    if ( size == 14 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[14] - s2[14];
    if ( size == 15 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[15] - s2[15];
    if ( size == 16 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[16] - s2[16];
    if ( size == 17 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[17] - s2[17];
    if ( size == 18 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[18] - s2[18];
    if ( size == 19 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    ret = s1[19] - s2[19];
    if ( size == 20 || ret != 0 )
        return ret;

    return memcmp( s1 + 20, s2 + 20, size - 20 );
}

void t1(){
    char *x = "hihihaha";
    printf("%d\n", _memcmp( x, "ha", 2 ));
}

void t2(){
    char *x = "hihihaha";
    printf("%d\n", _memcmp( x, "hi", 2 ));
}
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled with `03` flag, I got this message:

```
gcc-7 -O3 -Wall -o mem_cmp mem_cmp.c
mem_cmp.c: In function ‘_memcmp.part.0.constprop’:
mem_cmp.c:89:23: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
     return memcmp( s1 + 20, s2 + 20, size - 20 );
```

I've tried with `gcc-4.9` and `gcc-5` but no luck.

**Edit**:

I'm curious to know about why the warning appears rather than about the style of code. (I know well `memcmp`. Certainly `_memcmp` can be reimplemented by `for` but I want to gain even some cycles.)

Comment: What will be `s1+20` in case of `s1="hihihaha"`??? Also never use leading underscore in your names. Especially with the standard-like names such as `memcmp`.

Comment: From my experience, `-Warray-bounds` often produces false positives.

Answer (score 1):

Your `memcmp` assumes that the memory `s1+20` is within an array `s1` - which it is not. Even if the compiler didn't complain about this - you would get into undefined behavior (which may range from crashing of your program to correct execution. This is not what you should reply on.). Mostly from the string literals size which is known at compile tile it infers about this.

Correct one would be

```
return memcmp( s1, s2, min(strlen(s1),strlen(s2)));
```

where `min(x,y)` returns minimum of `x` and `y`.

First check the size and then access the array. First do the size checking then index into the array. repetitive code over here can be reduced using `for` loop. By that I mean whatever you are doing for different indices in those `if` statements can be packed into a single block, so that it can be used with for loop (with index variables denoting the changed value in each iteration).

Also note if you are using `memcmp` at last then don't go for checking characters individually - it is not needed. You can just check it directly using `memcmp` and then output the result.

Comment: @IljaEverilä.: Nice point - and it would be undefined behavior not necessarily runtime error (I should be more specific correctly).